# Can man do marriage with his mother in law after the divorce of her daughter?

Tags: nikah, sunni, talaq

Please give the answer quickly in my I.d address. Can a man do marriage with his mother in law after divorce of her daughter?

Comment: Dear tariq, to the best of my knowledge, it is haram for everyone to get married to his (their) mother(s)-in-laws forever. Since it is declared that She (the mother-in-law) would be mahram to you forever (even after the talaq (divorce) of her daughter to you). Consequently as an Islamic rule, it is haram (forbidden) to get married to maharem (persons who are mahram to you).
On the other hand, as @Medi-Saif named the Qur’anic verse correctly:

Prohibited to you [for marriage] are ..., your wives' mothers ... (4:23)

Answer (score 1):

This is even then haram if his wife died because of the Verse from surat an-Nisa ([4:23](http://legacy.quran.com/4/23)) which clearly mention

> Prohibited to you [for marriage] are ..., **your wives' mothers** ...

among those who are haram to marry (even if he didn't have intercourse with his former wife)! Under mothers we understand the mother in law and the grandmother of the (former) wife etc.

See also this [fatwa in Arabic](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/26819) or this [fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/20750) which answers the question starting from a kind of opposite point of view

And Allah knows best